# SSMS Display Separate Queries In Separate Results Tab

Tags: sql-server, ssms

In SQL Server Management Studio, if I run a query like

```
SELECT TOP 1000 *
  FROM SomeDB

SELECT TOP 1000 *
  FROM SomeOtherDB
```

The results display in one tab but split horizontally down the middle, is there any way to get the results of multiple queries to display in multiple tabs?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Tools -> Options -> Query Results -> Results To Grid -> Display Results in Separate Tab

This will show the results in a separate tab (though all result sets will be in that one tab).

As far as I know, there is no way to separate out the different result sets as you seem to want, apart from having separate query windows.

Comment: No this isn't what I want, this displays both results sets in the same tab, I want them in different tabs

Comment: =( OK thanks, it would be nice if there was a way to do it but I guess not.